# How to prevent memory demand increase in python to overcome out-of-memory error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, memory

I have a python code like below. As the for loop goes on memory use increases up and after a point python stops execution giving a out of memory error.

By doing some research I tried to close the figures by close() and clf methods. Doing them together reduced the memory buildup rate but could not make my code to complete. I think garbage collection did not help at all.

I cannot understand the reason for memory buildup since I delete the dataframe in each for loop.

I think it might help if I could figure out how to clean the memory completely except for some variables that I don't want to.

In some other posts some people recommended to use generators but I couldn't find one with a siple step-by-step guide.

Update: Tpe problem is with the figures/plotting. When I removed the plotting part from the code and just added the results to the text file the problem is solved. So how can all figure/plotting/etc. objects/variables/etc. can be removed from the memory completely?

Any help to overcome the problem is appreciated.

```
f = open("logfile.csv","w")
for a in arange(6,15,1):
    for b in arange(0.5,4,0.4):
        for c in arange(0.5,4,0.4):
            for d in arange(0.5,4,0.4):
                fig=figure( figsize=( 25, 3*len(z) ) )
                # create a pandas dataframe s by making computations with the previous ones
                # than plot some of its colums to a figure file  
                del s,v
                fig.savefig('plota=%d;b=%.1f;c=%.1f;d=%.1f.png' %(a,b,c,d) ) 
                fig.clf()
                plt.cla()
                plt.close(fig)
                plt.close()
                plt.close('all')
                gc.collect()
```

Comment: Did you check out what the (maximum) value of `len(z)` is?

Comment: len(z) is constant at 11